# Is there a way to Upload directories using Blazor InputFile?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

So in my usecase I want to Upload a whole directory to a Blazor-Server Application, but using the standard InputFile-Component only gives me a List of IBrowserFiles, which have no clear structure of where they are located in a Folder.

I'm kind of stuck and find no real solution on the Internet.

Here are the things I've tried already

```html
<InputFile id="fileInputProject" OnChange="UploadFilesFolder" hidden webkitdirectory directory/>

<MudButton for="fileInputProject">Upload Project</MudButton>
```

```cs
private async Task UploadFilesFolder(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File Input");
        List<IBrowserFile> files = e.GetMultipleFiles().ToList();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
        }
        
    }
```

I also use Mudblazor as a Component-Library, but that shouldn't do too much.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can zip it client side and then transfer it as one file. But this is not standard. InputFile = one file.

Comment: Yeah I now zipped it on the client and called it a day. Not the ideal solution but it works

Answer (score 2):

Directory Upload is not officially supported yet as it's waiting on `RelativePath` being supported by the `IBrowserFile` interface: [aspnetcore/#31638](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/31638).

However it is possible to fetch relative file structure in Blazor using C# with a little bit of JavaScript.

1. Create `wwwroot/js/fileFunctions.js` with the following:

```
window.getFileList = (inputFile) => {
    const fileList = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < inputFile.files.length; i++) {
        fileList.push(inputFile.files[i].webkitRelativePath);
    }

    return fileList;
};
```

2. Add the following code to your Razor page (`Home.razor`):

```
<InputFile @ref="inputFileRef" OnChange="@HandleFileSelection" multiple webkitdirectory/>

@code {
    InputFile inputFileRef;

    async Task HandleFileSelection(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        //Invoke JavaScript from C#
        var fileRelativePaths = await JS.InvokeAsync<string[]>("getFileList", inputFileRef.Element.Value);

        //Fetch files from InputFile
        var files = e.GetMultipleFiles();

        //Combine uploaded files with relative file paths
        List<BrowserFileWithPath> browserFilesWithPaths = fileRelativePaths.ToList().Select((relativePath, index) => new BrowserFileWithPath(files[index], relativePath)).ToList();

        foreach(var file in browserFilesWithPaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{file.BrowserFile.Name}, {file.RelativePath}");
        }
    }

    public record BrowserFileWithPath(IBrowserFile BrowserFile, string RelativePath);
}
```

This code uses [JavaScript Interoperability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) from Blazor to fetch the relative paths of files directly using JavaScript.